# retrieve the lowest three values from the array of javascript objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

hi guys i have a problem here, i want to get the lowest three values from the array of javascript objects. and the array of object is like this

```
let array = [{student_id: 'asda123asd1', nrw: 70}, {student_id: 'asda123asd2', nrw: 80}, {student_id: 'asda123asd3', nrw: 50}, {student_id: 'asda123asd4', nrw: 50}, {student_id: 'asda123asd5', nrw: 100}];
```

the result i want is like this

```
[{student_id: 'asda123asd3', nrw: 50}, {student_id: 'asda123asd4', nrw: 50},{student_id: 'asda123asd1', nrw: 70}]
```

i have tried this but didnt solve my problem

```
let test = async (array, n) => {
    let empty = []
    let MAX = 100000; 
    let firstmin = MAX; 
    let secmin = MAX; 
    let thirdmin = MAX; 
        for (let i = 0; i < n;i++) 
        { 
            
            /* Check if current element is less than 
            firstmin, then update first, second and 
            third */
            if (array[i].nrw < firstmin) 
            { 
                thirdmin = secmin; 
                secmin = firstmin; 
                firstmin = array[i].nrw; 
            } 
    
            /* Check if current element is less than 
            secmin then update second and third */
            else if (array[i].nrw < secmin) 
            { 
                thirdmin = secmin; 
                secmin = array[i].nrw; 
            } 
    
            /* Check if current element is less than 
            then update third */
            else if (array[i].nrw < thirdmin) 
                thirdmin = array[i].nrw; 


        }

        if(firstmin != 100000){
            empty.push({nrw: firstmin})
        }

        if(secmin != 100000){
            empty.push({nrw: secmin})
        }

        if(thirdmin != 100000){
            empty.push({nrw: thirdmin})
        }

        console.log(empty)

}
```

how can you guys solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mean you can use the inbuilt `sort` as well with a `custom` comparator function and just get the first three values.

```js
let array = [{student_id: 'asda123asd1', nrw: 70}, {student_id: 'asda123asd2', nrw: 80}, {student_id: 'asda123asd3', nrw: 50}, {student_id: 'asda123asd4', nrw: 50}, {student_id: 'asda123asd5', nrw: 100}];


array.sort((item1,item2)=>item1.nrw-item2.nrw);

console.log("First Item",array[0]);
console.log("Second Item",array[1]);
console.log("Third Item",array[2]);
```

Comment: Btw it will also work with your implementation. It's just that instead of storing `nrw` values in `firstMin`, `secondMin` and `thirdMin` - store the whole object and do comparisons like `array[i].nrw < firstmin.nrw`.

Comment: yes I think so too, I think there is just a little more to perfect it.
but I think the way of your implementation is better than mine.
thankyou

Answer (score 2):

You have the array:

```
let array = [{student_id: 'asda123asd1', nrw: 70}, {student_id: 'asda123asd2', nrw: 80}, {student_id: 'asda123asd3', nrw: 50}, {student_id: 'asda123asd4', nrw: 50}, {student_id: 'asda123asd5', nrw: 100}];
```

First you need to sort it based on the desired property:

```
array.sort((a ,b) => a.nrw - b.nrw);
```

Then pick the first three element:

```
const lowestThree = array.slice(0,3);
```

Comment: yes already solved, thank you guys, you saved my day :)